# Include headers in header files because of Qt moc

Tags: c++, qt

I try to stick to the principle of including headers in implementation files and not in .h files. But for qt projects I have to run most of my header files through moc which then complains about classes it doesn't know about. I use `moc header.h -o header.moc.cpp` and then link all cpp's and the .moc.cpp's together.
Example:

**header1.h** and a cpp file to go with it where I include header1.h at the top

```
#ifndef __HEADER_1_H
#define __HEADER_1_H

class Baseclass { /* ... */ };

#endif
```

**header2.h** and a cpp file to go with it where I include header1.h and header2.h at the top

```
#ifndef __HEADER_2_H
#define __HEADER_2_H
//here is where I then have to #include "header1.h" because of moc

class Derived: public QObject, public Base { Q_OBJECT; /* ... */ };
#endif
```

Now the problem is when I have another class in another header and cpp file:

**header3.h**
    #ifndef __HEADER_3_H
    #define __HEADER_3_H

```
//I have to include header2.h because moc doesn't know about Derived.

class Other : public QWidget { Q_OBJECT; Derived* d };
```

Then in an implementation file I need to use Derived and Other, but when I include their headers I obviously get multiple definition errors. I can circumvent this by including only header3.h which will in turn include the other headers.
I think this leads to very confusing code with unnecessarily included stuff and other invisibly included stuff (thus being error prone). How can I do this better?

Comment: If you get multiple definition error you obviously have an error in your header. Fix it.

Comment: You have been tried to use #pragma once instead?

Comment: I suggest throwing your policy into the trash.  I suggest you #include files in an #include to satisfy declarations.  For example, if one of your methods returns `std::string`, then put `#include <string>` into your header file.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews for the function declaration (even if the parameter is by value) you only need the forward declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple definitions because probably you have some function definitions in the header files, so move those to the corresponding .cpp files.

Now about includes:
You need the include (full type) for inheritance (not for moc):

```
#ifndef __HEADER_2_H
#define __HEADER_2_H
//here you need to include header1, because you inherit from that class 
//and this needs to see the whole object blueprint
//forward declaration is not enough.
#include <QObject>
#include "Baseclass.h" //or header1.h or whateven the file name is

class Derived: public QObject, public Baseclass { Q_OBJECT; /* ... */ };
#endif
```

You need full type for inheritance and for the `Derived` you can use forward declaration, because you only have a pointer:

```
//you need include for QWidget, because you inherit from it
#include <QWidget>
//and forward declaration for derived
Class Derived;

class Other : public QWidget { Q_OBJECT; Derived* d };
```

In the file other.cpp you'll need to include the "Derived.h" if you want to use functionality from `Derived`